# Promises with createReadStream and csv-parser

Tags: node.js, csv, es6-promise

Good evening,

I am trying to create function to read .csv data from a file.

In main.js I need to define the execution flow, which is why I am looking to use promises as shown in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y5mltEaQxa0.

I have managed to read data from a mongoose query, but I am struggling to make the below function work. When I `console.log(getCustomerData())` I get a `Promise{[]}` result.

```
const fs = require("fs");
const csv = require("csv-parser");

function getCustomerData(){

return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    const csvData = [];
    fs.createReadStream('complaints.csv')
    .pipe(csv())

    .on('data',(data)=> {
        csvData.push(
            [Number(data['c_id']),
            Number(data['category']),
            data['comments'].replace(/[\W_]+/g," "),
            String(data['date'].trim())])
        })

    .on('end',()=> {
        console.log(csvData)
    });
    if(csvData){
        resolve(csvData)
    }else{
        reject(Error("No data was found in the .csv"))
    }
})

}

getComplaints();

module.exports = getComplaints;
```

What I am trying to achieve is to parse the csv.file and return an array of arrays. The code prints the correct result, but I am unable to use it on a promise chain `f().then(()=> f2()).then...`

Could anybody give me a hand on this one?

Many thanks.

```
[...  [
    693,
    2,
    'Lorem Ipsum',
    '2019-01-24'
  ],
  [
    775,
    1,
    'Lorem Ipsum...',
    '2019-01-24'
  ],...]
```

Comment: Move your `if (csvData) resolve() else reject()` logic into `.on('end', () => ...` callback

Comment: @yqlim: Post this as an answer that the OP can accept :)